# Make a change to a string in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a queryset in Django that contains a string field. This is a filename, something like `images/photo.jpg` or `images/photo.20.19.22.jpg`. I need to rewrite them in one particular view so that ".thumbnail" is inserted before the extension. The previous names should become `images/photo.thumbnail.jpg` and `images/photo.20.19.22.thumbnail.jpg`.

What is the best way to do this? This is part of a queryset so it will look like:

```
{% for record in list %}
  {{ record.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now of course I would love to do this outside of my template. However, I don't see a way in which I can do that. After all, this needs to be done for every record inside my queryset. To complicate things, this record does not come directly from a modal. This record is coming from a subquery, so I don't see a way for me to change the modal itself. Should I use templatetags for this? Any other recommendations?

FYI the subquery is something like this:

```
>>> from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
>>> newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
>>> Post.objects.annotate(image=Subquery(newest.values('image')[:1]))
```

Comment: do you want to rename all the images inside a view ? also update your question with your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) could do this.

```
@register.filter
def add_thumbnail(image):
    return image.replace('.jpg', 'thumbnail.jpg')
```

And in the template:

```
{% for record in list %}
  {{ record.image|add_thumbnail }}
{% endfor %}
```